# Ionic async unit test with LoadingController

Tags: unit-testing, ionic-framework, jasmine, karma-runner

I have an Ionic Angular Application and I am trying to write a simple unit test for the service method. The method displays a Loading spinner and then returns true.

See the code below:

**Service.specs.ts**

```
import {
  TestBed,
  ComponentFixture,
  inject,
  fakeAsync,
  tick,
  flushMicrotasks,
} from '@angular/core/testing'; import { GeneralmethodsService } from './generalmethods.service';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';
import { AlertController, LoadingController, ModalController, ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { HandleNetworkService } from './handle-network.service';
import { TmmserviceService } from './tmmservice.service';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

describe('GeneralmethodsService xxx', () => {
  let modalController: ModalController;
  let tmmserviceServiceNatice: TmmserviceService;
  let loadingController: LoadingController;
  let router: Router;
  let toastController: ToastController;
  let translate: TranslateService;
  let Service: GeneralmethodsService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        GeneralmethodsService,
        {
          provide: LoadingController,
          useValue: {
            create: () => Promise.resolve(),
            dismiss: () => Promise.resolve()
          }
        }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();

    Service = new GeneralmethodsService(
      modalController,
      router,
      loadingController,
      tmmserviceServiceNatice,
      toastController,
      translate
    );
  });

  it('test testPist', fakeAsync(() => {
    return Service.testPist().then(async (data) => {
      expect(data).toBe(true);
      flushMicrotasks();
    });
  }));
});
```

Below you can see the method implementation in the service
**Service.ts**

```
  async testPist(){
    let loading = await this.loadingController.create();
    await loading.present();
    loading.dismiss();
    return true;
  }
```

This is the error I'm getting:

**Error**

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because the `loadingController` is undefined.

Follow the comments with !!

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        GeneralmethodsService,
        {
          provide: LoadingController,
          // !! You defined loading controller here in the TestBed module
          useValue: {
            create: () => Promise.resolve(),
            dismiss: () => Promise.resolve()
          }
        }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();

    // Service = new GeneralmethodsService(
      // modalController,
      // router,
      // !! at this point loadingController is undefined
      // loadingController,
      // tmmserviceServiceNatice,
      // toastController,
      // translate
    // );
    // !! comment out the above and get a handle on the service using the TestBed
     Service = TestBed.inject(GeneralMethodsService);
  });
```

Doing the above changes should hopefully get you unblocked. Since you have a `TestBed.configureTestingModule` and it is configured, we can use that to get a handle on the service under test.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did your suggestions 

Now it gives me the following error

``` 
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[GeneralmethodsService -> ModalController -> AngularDelegate -> AngularDelegate]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for AngularDelegate!
```

Comment: Is this wrong?

 !! You defined loading controller here in the TestBed module

Comment: If you could show me the constructor of your `GeneralmethodsService`, I can hopefully help. We need to mock all external dependencies (everything that is injected into the constructor) similarly to how `LoadingController` was mocked. You need to mock `ModalController` the same way.

Comment: This is my constructor

    public loadingController: LoadingController,
    private router: Router,
    public toastController: ToastController,
    public modalController: ModalController,
    public tmmserviceServiceNatice: TmmserviceService,
    public translate: TranslateService

I've managed to solve the dependencies issue. Now im getting 

Error: Uncaught (in promise): cordova_not_available

I dont know why

Comment: Ok, that's great. I am not sure about the cordova issue. Unfortunately I have more experience in Angular than Ionic.